# Puma systemd restart times out and seems to fail even though it has actually succeeded

Tags: systemd, puma

We have a systemd service that manages Puma processes, based on the suggested config [here](https://puma.io/puma/file.systemd.html).

Though it seems to work well, restarts time out and thus appear to have failed, even though they are successful. How does one debug this sort of problem? What is systemd expecting that it isn't getting?

```
$ systemctl restart puma
Job for puma.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status puma.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Yet:

```
$ systemctl status puma.service
● puma.service - Puma HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/puma.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Tue 2021-08-17 16:21:54 UTC; 30s ago
TriggeredBy: ● puma.socket
   Main PID: 1791114 (bundle)
      Tasks: 40 (limit: 7028)
     Memory: 561.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/puma.service
             ├─1791114 puma 4.3.8 (unix:///srv/app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock) [20210817160414]
             ├─1791178 puma: cluster worker 0: 1791114 [20210817160414]
             └─1791190 puma: cluster worker 1: 1791114 [20210817160414]

Aug 17 16:21:55 domain.tld bundle[1791114]: [1791114] * Environment: production
Aug 17 16:21:55 domain.tld bundle[1791114]: [1791114] * Process workers: 2
Aug 17 16:21:55 domain.tld bundle[1791114]: [1791114] * Preloading application
Aug 17 16:22:08 domain.tld bundle[1791114]: [1791114] * Activated unix:///srv/app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
Aug 17 16:22:08 domain.tld bundle[1791114]: [1791114] ! WARNING: Detected 2 Thread(s) started in app boot:
Aug 17 16:22:08 domain.tld bundle[1791114]: [1791114] ! #<Thread:0x0000585fceb5fcf8 /srv/nlr/app/shared/bundle/rub>
Aug 17 16:22:08 domain.tld bundle[1791114]: [1791114] ! #<Rack::MiniProfiler::FileStore::CacheCleanupThread:0x0000>
Aug 17 16:22:08 domain.tld bundle[1791114]: [1791114] Use Ctrl-C to stop
Aug 17 16:22:08 domain.tld bundle[1791114]: [1791114] - Worker 0 (pid: 1791178) booted, phase: 0
Aug 17 16:22:08 domain.tld bundle[1791114]: [1791114] - Worker 1 (pid: 1791190) booted, phase: 0
```

And:

```
    $ journalctl -xe
-- Automatic restarting of the unit puma.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Aug 17 16:24:56 domain.tld audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=puma comm=>
Aug 17 16:24:56 domain.tld audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=puma comm=">
Aug 17 16:24:56 domain.tld systemd[1]: Stopped Puma HTTP Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit puma.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit puma.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 142665 and the job result is done.
Aug 17 16:24:56 domain.tld systemd[1]: Starting Puma HTTP Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit puma.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit puma.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 142665.
Aug 17 16:24:57 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] Puma starting in cluster mode...
Aug 17 16:24:57 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] * Version 4.3.8 (ruby 2.7.4-p191), codename: Mysterious Trav>
Aug 17 16:24:57 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 16
Aug 17 16:24:57 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] * Environment: production
Aug 17 16:24:57 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] * Process workers: 2
Aug 17 16:24:57 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] * Preloading application
Aug 17 16:25:07 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] * Activated unix:///srv/app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
Aug 17 16:25:07 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] ! WARNING: Detected 2 Thread(s) started in app boot:
Aug 17 16:25:07 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] ! #<Thread:0x000062e706be2490 /srv/app/shared/bundle/rub>
Aug 17 16:25:07 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] ! #<Rack::MiniProfiler::FileStore::CacheCleanupThread:0x0000>
Aug 17 16:25:07 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] Use Ctrl-C to stop
Aug 17 16:25:07 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] - Worker 0 (pid: 1791747) booted, phase: 0
Aug 17 16:25:07 domain.tld bundle[1791690]: [1791690] - Worker 1 (pid: 1791756) booted, phase: 0
  [1]: https://puma.io/puma/file.systemd.html
```

puma.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

Requires=puma.socket

[Service]
Type=notify

WatchdogSec=10

User=app

WorkingDirectory=/srv/app/current

EnvironmentFile=/srv/app/current/.env

ExecStart=/srv/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec --keep-file-descriptors puma -C /srv/app/current/config/puma.rb

Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

puma.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server Accept Sockets

[Socket]
SocketUser=app
SocketGroup=app
ListenStream=/srv/app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock

NoDelay=true
ReusePort=true
Backlog=1024

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer was in the integration with `sd_notify`: using the "simple" type instead avoided the problem. No doubt it can be made to work with `sd_notify`, but this requires extra configuration to have one's app communicate state to `systemd`.

So instead of:

```
Type=notify
WatchdogSec=10
```

Use:

```
Type=simple
```

... unless you're going to figure out the `sd_notify` integration too.